# why when i rebind the reference of c++ , the compiler doesn't report error

Tags: c++

c++ primer 2.3.1 says : once initialized, a reference remains bound to its initial object . There is no way to rebind a reference to refer to a different object.
But my code works well:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    int &r = a;
    r = b;
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the running result is :

2

Comment: Try printing `a` along with `r`. There is no *rebinding*, you're simply assigning to `a` via the reference.

Comment: Once a reference is made, the reference the thing it references become synonyms in (virtually) every way.   Saying r=b is the same as saying a=b.

Answer (score 7):

You did not *rebind*.  Instead, you assigned the value of `b` to `a`.

Check this yourself by printing out the addresses before and after that assignment:

```
std::cout << "a: " << &a << std::endl;
std::cout << "b: " << &b << std::endl;
std::cout << "r: " << &r << std::endl;
```